# How to display the values from ajax success data to the html table?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I need to view the ajax success message in my html table 
my cshtml code is:

```
@*@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;
}*@
@{ 
            }

    <center><h1 style="color:red">User details</h1></center>

<div>
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>res.Id</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FIRST NAME</td>
            <td>res.Fname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LAST NAME</td>
            <td>res.Lname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LOCATION</td>
            <td>res.Location</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact</td>
            <td>res.Contact</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>res.Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td>res.Password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td>res.Category</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

    </table>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Details/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Welcome!');
                    res = data;


                   // window.location.href = "/Home/Details/" + data.id;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#postResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
                }
            });
    </script>
}
```

Is there any way to use the success data to pass in the each table row?
That is I want the res to store the success data and then pass it to the table fields like res.Fname (eg) and it should display the data accordingly.

Comment: you need to display value in one column alone or multiple columns

Comment: I need to display each value in the corresponding columns

Comment: If you are using razor pages this [repo](https://github.com/LazZiya/PagingSampleProject) and [demo](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/PagingAjax) can help you. Basically there is a partial view rendering the ajax part inside the main razor page. The project depends on a custom [PagingTagHelper](https://github.com/LazZiya/TagHelpers/wiki/Paging-TagHelper-Basic-Setup) with ajax support.

Comment: Did you have two projects , one web project and one web api ? Did  you want to use ajax in the web project to call the methods in the web api project and then display the return value in the web project?

Comment: @XueliChen i have one solution which contains 2 controllers api and home. All i want is that i just converted my home controller action controls to my view as ajax. but i could not get that value in my html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show value in one column alone then use this type

```
@*@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;
}*@
@{ 
            }

    <center><h1 style="color:red">User details</h1></center>

<div>
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td id="Id"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FIRST NAME</td>
            <td id="Fname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LAST NAME</td>
            <td id="Lname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>LOCATION</td>
            <td id="Location"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact</td>
            <td id="Contact"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td id="Email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td id="Password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Role</td>
            <td id="Category"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

    </table>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json",
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Details/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Welcome!');
                    res = data;
                    document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = res.Id;
                    document.getElementById("Fname").innerHTML= res.Fname;
                    document.getElementById("Lname").innerHTML= res.Lname;
                    document.getElementById("Location").innerHTML= res.Location;
                    document.getElementById("Contact").innerHTML= res.Contact;
                    document.getElementById("Email").innerHTML= res.Email;
                    document.getElementById("Password").innerHTML= res.Password;
                    document.getElementById("Category").innerHTML= res.Category;
                   // window.location.href = "/Home/Details/" + data.id;
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#postResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
                }
            });
    </script>
}
```

I think it will help you :)

Comment: get element by id works for table field. I mistakenly used value it should be innerHTML

Comment: Ok that worked fine. and can you also suggest to set table for all the elements in the list using loop. how to store that?

Comment: share me the table design which way you need to display list

Answer (score 3):

There are many way you can populate your table through `Ajax` response. Here the most readable and popular  way you could try. See the below code snippet.

```
<table id="YourTableId" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive table-hover">  
    <thead>  
        <tr>  
            <th align="left" class="yourTableTh">YourProperty</th>  
            <th align="left" class="yourTableTh">YourProperty2</th>  
            <th align="left" class="yourTableTh">YourProperty3</th>  
        </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody></tbody>  
</table>                

<script>
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Details/" + id,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Welcome!');
               // res = data;
                        var items = '';  
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {  
                            var rows = "<tr>"  
                            + "<td class='yourTableTh'>" + item.YourProperty + "</td>"  
                            + "<td class='yourTableTh'>" + item.YourProperty2 + "</td>"  
                            + "<td class='yourTableTh'>" + item.YourProperty3 + "</td>"  
                            + "</tr>";  
                            $('#YourTableId tbody').append(rows);  
                        });  

               // window.location.href = "/Home/Details/" + data.id;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#postResult").val(jqXHR.statusText);
            }
        });
</script>
```

***Another Way Using C# Viewbag:***

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Property Header</th>
                        <th>Property Header</th>
                        <th>Property Header</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ViewBagName)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.PropertyName</td>
                            <td>@item.PropertyName</td>
                            <td>@item.PropertyName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
   </table>
```

Let me know if you have any additional question.
 Hope that would help.

Comment: is there a way to call that success data to that table without this method you have given?

Comment: There any many way, but looping is common because you have to populate a table. But in some `JavaScript ` framework supports without looping over response data.

Comment: which way you are expecting could give me a hints?

Comment: @MdFaridI need to get my data on the table buy using an object like we use viewbag in C#. here i want that success data to be contained in  variable and i need that to pass each data in that table. is it possible to do like that?

Comment: Yes you can do that in that case you have to tune few things `1.` @{
    var yourVariable= ViewBag.ViewBagName;
} `2.` @foreach(var item in yourVariable)
{
    <p>@item .value</p>
} `3.` Its case sensitive name convention should be as per your collection. hope you understand

Comment: but in that case how my success data is used there if possible can you just edit my code.

Comment: I have updated my answer with that example as well.

Comment: this is not what i meant.. can i take that success data as view bag to use it in my code shown in my question section? (i know C# viewbag all i wanted how to use that in script)

Comment: You can use it like this `var yourVarable = '@ViewBag.ViewBagName';` inside you script but good practice I have already show you on answer.

Comment: Additionally, if your `viewBag` contains list type data then you have to iterate over to extract that value.

Comment: no i have used the same way but the values is blank in the fields

Comment: I would highly suggestion you to try my answer. It would work. this is not recommended  `var yourVarable = '@ViewBag.ViewBagName';`

Comment: actually i had done crud in c# and everything works fine and i need to convert that c# to js in the cshtml so when i use your shown answer i need to rewrite all my api and repository again.

Comment: I hope you had gone through another answer of AakashRajni it also doesn't fect the data in each fields all data is fetched from he list but it doesn;t bind to the corresponding fields. it is not showing the data in the html page

Comment: Absolute not. you need not to rewrite your code at all.

Comment: I have got it thanks. Actually it worked on another project and here i needed another type and i got it thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Partial view to contain the table data and  return `PartialViewResult` from the api controller  ,then show the partial view from  the success function of ajax . The following is the steps:

*_DetailsPartial*

```
@model DemoTest.Models.User

<center><h1 style="color:red">User details</h1></center>

<div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>@Model.Id</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FIRST NAME</td>
        <td>@Model.Fname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LAST NAME</td>
        <td>@Model.Lname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LOCATION</td>
        <td>@Model.Location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Contact</td>
        <td>@Model.Contact</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>@Model.Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>@Model.Password</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Role</td>
        <td>@Model.Category</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Api controller ,return PartialViewResult

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DemoDbContext _context;
    public ValuesController(DemoDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        var user = await _context.User.FindAsync(id);

        var myViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary()) 
        { { "User", user } };
        myViewData.Model = user;
        return new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName= "_DetailsPartial",
            ViewData= myViewData
        };
    }
}
```

The main view that contains the partial view, use ajax to show the result of success function in the `<div id="userdetail"></div>`

```
<div id="userdetail"></div>

@section Scripts{
 <script>
    var id = 1;
        $.ajax({
            //contentType: "application/json",
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://localhost:44343/api/Values/Details/" + id,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Welcome!');
                $("#userdetail").html(data);


               // window.location.href = "/Home/Details/" + data.id;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Failed!');
            }
        });
 </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

For more details about Partial View , you could refer to [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1).